# How can I kill a rectangle of text in Emacs if the first and last lines are not long enough?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs, I sometimes want to kill or copy a rectangle of text such as this one:

```
XX first line
XX second line is longer
XX 3rd line short
```

I want to copy the three lines without the leading "XX" on every line. However, it is impossible to mark both corners of the required rectangle, because the first and third lines do not reach to the right edge of the rectangle that I'm after. So how would I copy the three lines above without the leading "XX" in emacs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start marking the rectangle from the first line and when you are at the end of the 3d line then just type spaces until the line is long enough. That's what I usually do.

After copying you can type `M-\` (`delete-horizontal-space`) to remove the added spaces.

Comment: If  delete-selection mode is on then press C-g after marking the start of the rectangle. This cancels the highlighting, but the mark stays active, so further steps work as described.

Comment: Yes, you're right, mark will stay active, so cancel the selection will still work

Comment: You can't always do this (for example, when the buffer is read-only).  It looks like `rectangle-mark-mode` will be [fixed in Emacs 25](http://endlessparentheses.com/new-in-emacs-25-1-better-rectangles.html), though.

Answer (score 4):

I see two options that jump out.

The first is to use <kbd>M-x artist-mode</kbd>,
this will let you move to the position on the first/last line you want.
At which point you cut the rectangle <kbd>C-x r k</kbd>, and then paste
it wherever you want.  Don't forget to type <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to exit [artist mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ArtistMode).

The second is to just cut all three lines using the regular <kbd>C-w</kbd>
and then when you paste, delete the rectangle of `XX`s at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: You do not need to enter `artist-mode` to use `C-x r k`. Just mark the top-left and bottom-right corners of the rectangle you want. As for expanding to hit the third line, hit the space bar.

Comment: @jeremiahd - using `artist-mode` is an alternative to pressing space, you just use the movement bindings.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just pointing out that it's not necessary for the behavior requested in the question.

Comment: @jeremiahd Yes, and pressing spaces (your answer) isn't necessary either, that's why we have two different answers.  You'll notice that my answer doesn't require the user to delete the horizontal whitespace.

Comment: Right, that's why I posted a comment instead of an answer; it was meant as an aside, not a correction

Comment: `quarter-plane.el` (which is in GNU ELPA) is an alternative to `artist-mode` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the [cua-selection-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode) (M-x cua-selection-mode).

It allows you to do what you want, but only in the graphical emacs (not in the Terminal).  The key bindings are a bit different: you start the region with C-RET (instead of C-SPC) and cut/yank the rectangle simply with C-w/C-y (not using the rectangle commands).

You can find an example in [this blog](http://babbagefiles.blogspot.com/2011/01/latex-table-manipulation-using.html).

To permanently enable the mode just add

```
(cua-selection-mode t)
```

to your .emacs.

P.S. the full cua-mode will also change further key bindings.  It is not necessary to use it.

Comment: The rectangle selection is slightly awkward in this situation, but if you start at the top left, move to the end of the longest line, and then down to the last line, it works out.

Answer (score 0):

simple modifications of inbulit defuns. `kill-right-rectangle` function does what you want.
I am sure there would much better way to do it. Nonetheless it works.

Two points about the following code.
 - Since the idea is to get the text upto end of the line, you don't even need to specify the last column. simply mark at first line (in you example point at "f") and go down to third line to "3" call the function. (we only need one column, so don't need to move cursor to any right)
 - this doesn't work if the buffer is read only. its just not implemented.

```
(defun end-column (POINT)
  "returns end column"
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char POINT)
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (current-column)))

(defun apply-on-right-rectangle (function start end &rest args)
  (let (startcol startpt endcol endpt final-point)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char start)
      (setq startcol (current-column))
      (beginning-of-line)
      (setq startpt (point))
      (goto-char end)
      (setq endcol (current-column))
      (forward-line 1)
      (setq endpt (point-marker))
      ;; ensure the start column is the left one.
      (if (< endcol startcol)
          (let ((col startcol))
            (setq startcol endcol endcol col)))
      ;; start looping over lines
      (goto-char startpt)
      (while (< (point) endpt)
        (setq endcol (end-column (point)))
        (apply function startcol endcol args)
        (setq final-point (point))
        (forward-line 1)))
    final-point))

(defun delete-extract-right-rectangle (start end &optional fill)
  (let ((lines (list nil)))
    (apply-on-right-rectangle 'delete-extract-rectangle-line start end lines fill)
    (nreverse (cdr lines))))

(defun kill-right-rectangle (start end &optional fill)
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (condition-case nil
      (setq killed-rectangle (delete-extract-right-rectangle start end fill))
    ((buffer-read-only text-read-only)
     (setq killed-rectangle (extract-rectangle start end))
     (if kill-read-only-ok
         (progn (message "Read only text copied to kill ring") nil)
       (barf-if-buffer-read-only)
       (signal 'text-read-only (list (current-buffer)))))))
```